# Unable to Display image in recyclerview

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

trying to display a lsit of images to the recyclerview after passing it to recyclerview in an arraylist, but unable to display it.
I am passing image uri to the dataadapter and received successfully,
but still not able to display image in recycler view
please point out mistake.
The image is not displayed in recyclerview layout.

Main Activity.

```
public class SelectedImagePreview extends AppCompatActivity {
    private BitmapFactory.Options options;
    private RecyclerView viewPager;
    private View btnNext, btnPrev;
    private DataAdapter adapter;
    private LinearLayout thumbnailsContainer;
    ArrayList<File> mainfile = new ArrayList<>();
    File allfile;
    ArrayList<String> filename = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<Uri> images_uri = new ArrayList<Uri>();
    //the images to display
    String[] imageIDs;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.preview_activity);
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        viewPager = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        if (extras != null) {
            //filename.add(extras.getString("filename"));
            filename = (ArrayList<String>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("filename");
            Log.e("filename1111", String.valueOf(filename));
            Uri imageUri = getIntent().getData();
            Log.e("uri", String.valueOf(imageUri), null);
            allfile = new File(String.valueOf(imageUri));
            mainfile.add(allfile);
            images_uri.add(imageUri);
            Log.e("name", allfile.getName());
            Log.e("name33333333333333", mainfile.toString());

        }
        adapter = new DataAdapter(this, images_uri);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

DataAdapter.java

```
package www.welkinfort.com.whatsappgallery;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by Admin on 04-Sep-17.
 */

public class DataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DataAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<Uri> file_url;
    private Context context;

    public DataAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<Uri> file_url) {
        this.context = context;
        this.file_url = file_url;
        Log.e("filefggdgdgdgd",file_url.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public DataAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int position) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_layout, viewGroup, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
        viewHolder.img_android.setImageURI(file_url.get(position));
        //Picasso.with(context).load(file_url.get(i)).resize(120, 60).into(viewHolder.img_android);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return file_url.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        ImageView img_android;
        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            img_android = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.img_android);
        }
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/view_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

adpter layouy.java

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/img_android" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: are you receiving correct URL of image in adapter?

Comment: Could `file_url.get(position)` show normal in the network?

Comment: try if you are able to get single image with position 0 like this Picasso.with(context).load(file_url.get(0)).resize(120, 60).into(viewHolder.img_android);

Comment: how do you do setImageURI ? (on another note - use Glide or Picasso for better results)

Comment: Also check if the URL string doesn't have spaces , this might be the problem if so do replaceall() in the string to change it

Comment: yes @MurliPrajapati

Comment: My Actvity shows blank screen no with no image in imageview @yanivtwin

Comment: show code for setImageURI ()

Comment: setImageURI() is not a method is automatically called when i called this statement to setimageURI @yanivtwin